# How can I visually name a graph as a whole in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

How can I visually name a graph as a whole in Mathematica, not just edges and vertices? I've tried every which way but nothing suggested works. I'd also like to generate or use a list of names when creating a number of graphs, such as with Table. Wrapping a graph in Labelled only seems to work with one graph when I want to name a series of them. Also, labelled doesn't really name the graph programmatically, so the name can be used in place of the graph.

Comment: Please add a minimal example and/or/such as a list of graphs that you want labeled. Thanks.

Comment: What does "visually" name mean, exactly?  Do you mean `g = Graph[{a -> b]`, giving the name `g`?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Labeled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html)? There's also just `PlotLabel`: `Graph[{1->2}, PlotLabel -> "A label"]`

Comment: The question is not very clear. You first say "visually name", then "the name can be used in place of the graph", which seem to be different things, and which are also quite vague. I suggest describing the problem in terms of what you want to achieve instead of how you want to achieve it. For example, "I need to plot a graph and show a label above it".

Answer (score 2):

```
{happy, dopey, sleazy} = Table[RandomGraph[{20, 40}], 3];

happy
```